# What is the status of cloudsim?

Tags: cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I remember being quite excited about the possibility of remote, scalable deployments of `gzserver` after attending the "Cloudy With a Chance of Simulation" presentation by Ian Chen at ROSCon16, and as I'm now looking for approaches to do something similar I was wondering if someone could provide an update on the status of Cloudsim.

Google returns quite some results (mostly bitbucket/atlassian links (repositories, wikis, etc), SRC pages, etc), but not too many posts on Gazebo Answers. #q13253 was the only one I could find. @nkoenig writes there:

> It is on our roadmap for Gazebo 8.0, and is under development. Stay tuned.

With the Gazebo 9 release party almost here, what are the plans for Cloudsim?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18436/what-is-the-status-of-cloudsim?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4515/gvdhoorn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Development of Cloudsim has stalled over the past 1+ years. There are many reasons for this, which are related to time and other obligations.

We may find time in the future to circle back around to Cloudsim, but there are no immediate plans.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4515/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-03**:
Thanks for your answer.

"Development of Cloudsim has stalled over the past 1+ years."

That is unfortunate. It looks like it could be a really convenient way to work with Gazebo (server). Regrettably I'm not a webdev, so would be dependent on others to continue the work.